# How to prevent IIS from recycling Application Pool when a worker process is unresponsive

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wcf, iis

We have a WCF service which handles great amount of requests.

As I discovered, when the number of cuncurrent requests exceed the limit of max cuncurrent connections, the consequent requests will be queued up to be executed later. if time-out happens before these requests have a chance to execute, IIS determins worker process in unresponsive and kills it (or recycles the app pool).

The recycling process takes about one minute and meanwhile the service will be down which is a big problem for us.

Regardless of the cause of timeout and long response time in the code (which we are already working on it), my question is this:

If we define more than one worker-process for this app-pool, what will happen if one of worker-processes is in the same situation? Does IIS recycle the app-pool or the particular worker-process will be killed and other ones keep serving the requests?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a several working processes in the app-pool (so called web garden) and one of them exceeds the limit of requests/memory/does not respond on ping, all of them will be recycled.

http://www.treeloop.com/blog/iis-application-domain-and-pool-recycling